# No Session found for current thread] when invoke Service method

Tags: spring, hibernate, session

I try invoke my method which return admin lists, but when I invoke this method i get the error no session found.

roo-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="HR" />
        <property name="password" value="asdfghj" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.piotr.ibank.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="pl.piotr.ibank.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

</beans>
```

servlet-context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.piotr.ibank" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import pl.piotr.ibank.daointerface.UserDao;
import pl.piotr.ibank.model.User;
import pl.piotr.ibank.serviceinterface.UserService;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void createUser(User user) {
        userDao.createUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        userDao.deleteUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {
        return userDao.getUser(id);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public List getAdminList() {
        return userDao.getAdminList();
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDao.findByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

UserService interface:

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.serviceinterface;

import java.util.List;

import pl.piotr.ibank.model.User;

public interface UserService {

    void createUser(User user);

    void updateUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(int id);

    User getUser(int id);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List getAdminList();

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserDaoImpl

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import pl.piotr.ibank.daointerface.UserDao;
import pl.piotr.ibank.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void createUser(User user) {
        getCurrentSession().save(user);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        getCurrentSession().update(user);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        User user = getUser(id);
        if (user != null) {
            getCurrentSession().delete(user);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {
        User user = (User) getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
        return user;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public List getAdminList() {
        return getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "from User u, UserRole ur where u.id = ur.user.id and ur.user = 'ROLE_ADMIN'")
                .list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        System.out.println(username);

        try {
            users = getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery("from User where username=:username")
                    .setParameter("username", username).list();

            System.out.println("Liczba " + users.size());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (users.size() > 0) {
            return users.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

UserDao interface:

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.daointerface;

import java.util.List;

import pl.piotr.ibank.model.User;

public interface UserDao {

    void createUser(User user);

    void updateUser(User user);

    void deleteUser(int id);

    User getUser(int it);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List getAdminList();

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Controller which invoke getAdminList:

```
    package pl.piotr.ibank.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import pl.piotr.ibank.model.User;
import pl.piotr.ibank.serviceinterface.UserService;

@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/adminlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goAdminList() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("admin/adminlist");
        List<User> admins = userService.getAdminList();
        mav.addObject("admins", admins);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Login method work good, loadbyusername, but when i invoke method service.getAdminList() i have this error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ibank] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread] with root cause
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Comment: `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` does not work unless you have a session context defined, which it does not look like you do. You need to configure the [`OpenSessionInViewInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html).

Comment: But for `findByUsername` method getCurrentSession work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I find that in your code you auto wire 'Sessionfactory' in your DAO implement, which means that you needs to handle session manually, including open session and close session when necessary. Since you  are using Spring and hibernate, I suggest to use Template like HiberateTemplate, which Spring will take care of session for you. Every time you want to use session, just call 'getCurrentSession()', like what you are doing in you code.

Try to make a abstract DAO class that extends HibernateDaoSupport, like

public abstract class BasicDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport{
   ......
}

For your DAO implement, extends this class, and you code would work fine.